# Trouble port PhoneGap project to Windows Phone

Tags: dojo, windows-phone-8, cordova, esri

Porting [www.canterburymaps.govt.nz](http://www.canterburymaps.govt.nz/) to PhoneGap has been successful for Android and iOS, but Windows Phone (8) is causing issues.

The site works if viewed through IE, but when hosted within Cordova the Windows Phone app loads but there's issues with the functionality. We've discovered it's failing on the JavaScript "dojo.require" e.g.

```
dojo.require('dijit.layout.BorderContainer');
```

It doesn't seem to matter which library is passed in, so it seems to be an issue with the dojo.require function itself.

I've found this example online - http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/05/using-esri-arcgis-in-phonegap-applications - and have followed step 3 to change the root url in dojo, but this doesn't seem to help.

Anyone have any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: I did encounter same problem with PhoneGap and dojo.require. I tracked the bug down to PhoneGap/Cordova in Windows phone. It appears that PhoneGap intercepts the XHR calls made my dojo.require and tries to find that file locally on phones isolated storage. I was not able to find out a fix/workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

- Please mention the version numbers of both Dojo and PhoneGap.
- If you are not using the latest available for both, can you try upgrading?
- You mentioned that you tried changing the root URL, but did you try to configure the Dojo loader in sync mode (vs async)? Say data-dojo-config="async: 0, ..." in the script tag which loads dojo.js. Does it work better?